# Change bar button item programmatically after user presses it Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to make a feature where if the user presses the speaker button (a bar button item), then a speaker with a slash through it will replace the original button. Is there an easy way of doing this? I know that it must be done programatically but I can't figure out how to replace the speaker button with a different button.

[Here is a screenshot of my storyboard]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL3df.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an action for `UIBarButtonItem` on your `UIViewController` class by control dragging it into the ViewController's declaration. Then change the item

```
@IBAction func barButtonAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    sender.image = UIImage(named: "myNewImage")
}
```